# Display Brightness Scaling is Incorrect on a VAIO CW

Tags: 11.04, display, brightness, vaio

My display brightness adjustment is off by a factor of 10, i.e. it's brightest at 10% instead of at 100%, and the difference between 0% and 1% is a little too high.

Any way to fix either of these problems? (VAIO CW laptop)

Comment: You should report this as a bug, not sure about the package though.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: For some reason, I just don't yet feel very comfortable creating an account on Launchpad (and related) sites. I was supposed to report something else as well, but I don't think I'm going to, unfortunately. :\

Comment: A LP account can be used for multiple services related to Ubuntu: Launchpad (bugs, code, answers) and Ubuntu Wiki. If you sign up, you'll have to provide an e-mailaddress to which a confirmation mail is sent. See also https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount

Comment: As for the original question, does it happen with your keyboard shortcut or an applet? If you run `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, is your brightness set to 100%?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: acpi_video0 doesn't even exist. (I have an NVIDIA card.)

Comment: replace it by something sensible (`ls /sys/class/backlight` shows possible names) I've a nvidia card too

Comment: @Lekensteyn: When I try `cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/max_brightness | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness`, I get back 1025, and it maximizes the screen brightness -- but the value in Power Management doesn't change at all.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: It seems like my display's *actual* bounds are exactly 11 and 110 (or 109?).

Comment: a max_brightness of 1025 seems excessive to me, mine ranges from zero to seven.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Weird. Mine definitely goes from 11 to 110, and the rest is just full brightness. I'm guessing that 100% in Power Management corresponds to 1025 and that 10% to 110, hence the bug... idk the reason, though.

Comment: @Mehrdad Are you still having this issue, or have you found a resolution (or alternately, found or filed a bug report)?

Answer (score 2):

From the information you've given us, it appears that you need to change your GRUB settings.

To do that, open up a terminal and run the following commands:

`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub` - what that command will do is open Gedit in "Sudo Mode" and have the GRUB configuration file open.

Then, change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Brightness problem should be solved.

Comment: I had high hopes for this, but it didn't seem to work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and have the same problem.
What i have found is that if you go in to gnome configuration editor (gconf-editor) there you navigate to apps, gnome-power-manager, backlight. If i change the key brightness_ac from values 0-12 it affects my screen brightness. However values over 12 up to 100 doesn't make any difference to the brightness compared to 12.
When i use the fn+ f5, f6 keys it seams to adjust the brightness in values from 0-100 with increments of 5.
I hope this make sense for someone with more knowledge in ubuntu then me